# How much energy is converted in light when you burn a candle?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

When a candle burns the reaction is C25H52 + 38 O2 → 25 CO2 + 26 H2O. So it seems equal at both sides. But isn't there any light and heat (low elektromagnetic waves) produced. So how many Joule is produced of light of each candle molecule?

Comment: It is not possible to deduce a value from this information.

Comment: Couldn't there be made an aproximation or what is needed more to know to get a value?

Comment: An ordinary candle has a luminous intenity of about 1 cd (candela). You can convert that to a power (assuming a median wavelenght), multiply it with the time your candle burns, and compare with the delta H in your reaction.

Comment: See [How to Find the Molar Heat of a Combustion Candle](http://www.ehow.com/how_12040726_molar-heat-combustion-candle.html) for a detailed explanation and answer.